# How do you estimate multiple poisson rates simultaneously?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, poisson-regression, multinomial-distribution

I have data showing the number of cause-specific deaths in a cohort. I want to use Poisson regression to estimate the cause-specific rate by age. The complication is that I want the predicted cause-specific rates to add-up to the predicted all-cause rate.

Here is some data in R format, showing the total duration of follow-up in the cohort by age (`person_years`), the number of all-cause deaths (`all_cause`), and the number of deaths due to three causes: accidents (`accidents`), non-communicable diseases such as heart disease (`ncd`), and other (`other`):

```
d <- structure(list(age = 18:90, person_years = c(11, 213, 174, 155, 
53, 151, 75, 121, 198, 274, 205, 148, 286, 178, 256, 199, 345, 
223, 242, 319, 301, 401, 350, 272, 303, 457, 467, 387, 364, 470, 
346, 426, 424, 388, 377, 415, 540, 378, 433, 391, 410, 435, 314, 
441, 399, 286, 300, 334, 320, 371, 381, 288, 288, 375, 236, 190, 
316, 212, 306, 250, 321, 290, 309, 178, 137, 225, 113, 163, 237, 
175, 204, 111, 23), all_cause = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 17L, 16L, 
17L, 10L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 30L, 20L, 17L, 22L, 17L, 25L, 27L, 26L, 
29L, 34L, 41L, 29L, 30L, 60L, 36L, 58L, 56L, 94L, 50L, 90L, 58L, 
45L, 88L, 36L, 59L, 113L, 75L, 139L, 78L, 21L), accidents = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ncd = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 13L, 
15L, 16L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 26L, 17L, 11L, 20L, 10L, 17L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 28L, 26L, 25L, 23L, 44L, 29L, 45L, 43L, 72L, 31L, 73L, 
50L, 36L, 69L, 29L, 36L, 94L, 56L, 118L, 69L, 17L), other = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 
8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 15L, 4L, 7L, 16L, 7L, 13L, 13L, 22L, 18L, 17L, 
8L, 9L, 19L, 7L, 23L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 9L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-73L))
```

We can use Poisson regression to fit a curve on the all-cause rate. In this model, I've used age and age squared:

```
model1 <- glm(all_cause ~ poly(age, 2) + offset(log(person_years)), data = d, family = 'poisson')
```

We can predict the age-specific mortality rate and compare this to the observed rates graphically:

```
model1 <- glm(all_cause ~ poly(age, 2) + offset(log(person_years)), data = d, family = 'poisson')
newdata <- data.frame(age = d$age, person_years = 100000)
d$predicted_all_cause <- predict(model1, type = 'response', newdata = newdata)
d$observed_all_cause <- d$all_cause / d$person_years * 100000
plot(d$age, d$observed_all_cause, ylab = 'mortality rate per 100,000', xlab = 'age')
lines(d$age, d$predicted_all_cause)
```

[image]

So that works fine, but if we did something similar with each cause of death, the predicted rates would not add up to the all-cause rate we just estimated. If we fit a separate model for each cause of death ...

```
m_accidents <- glm(accidents ~ poly(age, 2) + offset(log(person_years)), data = d, family = 'poisson')
m_ncd <- glm(ncd ~ poly(age, 2) + offset(log(person_years)), data = d, family = 'poisson')
m_other <- glm(other ~ poly(age, 2) + offset(log(person_years)), data = d, family = 'poisson')
```

... Then predict the age-specific rates ...

```
d$predicted_accidents <- predict(m_accidents, type = 'response', newdata = newdata)
d$predicted_ncd <- predict(m_ncd, type = 'response', newdata = newdata)
d$predicted_other <- predict(m_other, type = 'response', newdata = newdata)
```

... When we add them up, they don't equal the all-cause rate. The head of the table comparing the two is shown below.

```
d$sum_predicted_cause_specific <- d$predicted_accidents + d$predicted_ncd + d$predicted_other
head(d[, c('age', 'predicted_all_cause', 'sum_predicted_cause_specific')])

  age predicted_all_cause sum_predicted_cause_specific
1  18            102.2936                     108.3501
2  19            111.8447                     118.4173
3  20            122.2923                     129.3918
4  21            133.7212                     141.3514
5  22            146.2239                     154.3805
6  23            159.9019                     168.5714
```

The fact they are different is not surprising since the curves are estimated separately. But I want them to add up exactly, so that the modelled all-cause rate 'decomposes' into the modelled cause-specific rates. The two approaches I've considered are:

1. a multivariate poisson model, for example using `vgam::vglm`, but this model will not force the sum of cause-specific rates to add up to the all-cause rate.
2. estimating the all-cause rate using `glm` and then using multinomial logistic regression to estimate the proportion at each age that are due to each cause of death. This seems like it might work, but feels complicated.

I can't figure out the best approach. I'm happy to use any common statistical software.

Comment: This looks like a case to use multinomial regression to me - you could consider using the functions nnet::multinom or mclogit::mblogit in R. Both are compatible also with emmeans and marginaleffects in case you would like to calculate marginal means and confidence intervals.

Comment: Do you mean option 2 above? Would you first calculate the proportion of deaths for each cause, then use the proportions as the dependent variable in multinomial regression?

Comment: Yes - factor cause of death would be your outcome variable and as observation weights you have to pass the count for each. I think you could also pass the log of person years as an offset. mclogit::mblogit also supports estimating overdispersion, or allows adding random effects. You can also use the poisson trick to reparameterize a multinomial model as a poisson one, but it's not so efficient for large datasets.